# Animation similar to iPhone Camera App where the captured image drops into the picture viewer

Tags: ios, camera

I'm working on a iOS camera app, and want to create an animation similar to what the default camera app does on capturing an image (not the shutter animation). The captured image seems to drop into the photo viewer located at the bottom left corner of the screen. Any ideas on how to achieve this? I have not tried animating view controllers before, so I'm a bit lost on how to do it.

*** EDIT Implementation issues ***
So I've learned how to do the animation, and the animation seems to work fine with a test Image but when I use the actual image returned from the AVCapture connection, the animation goes haywire. The image looks distorted (something wrong with the aspect ratio) and the path it follows is opposite to the actual one. This is the code I'm using to animate:

```
- (void)animateImage:(UIImage*) image {

  UIImageView *animator = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
  animator.frame = previewView.frame;
  animator.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
  [self.previewView addSubview:animator];

  [CATransaction begin]; {
      [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
              [animator removeFromSuperview];
      }];

    // Set up scaling
      CABasicAnimation *resizeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
    // Set to value to (0,0) rectangle
    [resizeAnimation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(0,0)]];
    resizeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    resizeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    // Set up path movement
    CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
    pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    //Setting Endpoint of the animation
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake( animator.frame.size.width, animator.frame.size.height); 
    CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, 0, 0);
  //  CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, animator.frame.size.width/2, animator.frame.size.height/2);
  //  CGPathAddCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, 0,0,0,0, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
    pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
    CGPathRelease(curvedPath);

    CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
 //   group.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards; // keep the final value after completion of animation
 //   group.removedOnCompletion = NO; // "
    [group setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: pathAnimation,  resizeAnimation, nil]];
    group.duration = 3.0f;
    group.delegate = self;
    [group setValue:animator forKey:@"imageViewBeingAnimated"];

    [animator.layer addAnimation:group forKey:@"cameraAnimation"];
} [CATransaction commit];
}
```

It seems to work when I take the picture in landscape  mode, but not in Portrait . It's something to do with orientation, but I cant figure out what could be wrong..

"previewView" frame is the AVCapture Preview Layer over which I add the UIImage and then scale and move it to a corner.

*** Final EDIT ***
Fixed using the transform property instead of bounds.size. Similar to the example here:
http://www.verious.com/article/animating-interfaces-with-core-animation-part-3/
Phew!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really this is quite simple, after the photo is taken, stick the returned UIimage in a UIImageView and then use core animation blocks to resize and animate the frame whilst making the imageview follow a bezierpath down to the photo viewer in the botton left corner.

Let me know if you need any further help with these steps.

Comment: Awesome thanks, it sounds quite simple when you put it that way :)

Comment: No problem, let me know if you need any help with any of these steps and I will supply sample code...

Comment: I've managed to get some animation working, but I seem to have a strange problem with the image orientation, could you have a look?